# What key works like End using a Mac with Synergy

Tags: windows, mac, iphone, keymap, synergy

I have recently got a Mac mini to do IPhone Dev on (like many others) and I am using the excellent [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) to share one keyboard and mouse with 2 machines and 2 monitors.  Everything is lovely and it works a treat.

I got used to using the mac, and the alt key works like command button on the mac however one thing I cant figure out is the End key.  I use this a lot on windows when wanting to jump to the end of a line of text, however if I press it over synergy on my mac it jumps to the end of the page.

Anyone know the key combination I need to get what I want?

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming im afraid. Try superuser.com

Comment: "I dont think many people on superuser will even know what synergy is" -- I think you're wrong :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does cmd-right do what you want?  It may be app-specific.

Comment: Cmd-Right, is often correct....

Traditionally End on the mac, means end of the field, which for a text box is the end of the end text...

Down Arrow may also work with single line text field.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, you should add that as an answer rather than just as a comment.  Thanks for the extra info. - Toby

Answer (score 0):

Fn-right arrow acts equivalently to "End".

Answer (score 0):

Command+Right for end, Command+Left for home.  Sometimes control+A is home, and control+E is end.

This question has inspired a more specific one [here](https://superuser.com/questions/126257/remapping-home-end-from-pc-to-mac-via-synergy-is-not-client-specific).

If you read this you might find that the best thing for you to do is to install [KeyFixer](http://www.starryhope.com/tech/apple/2006/keyfixer/) and the other hints for specific programs mentioned in that answer.