# Remapping Home/End from PC to Mac Via Synergy is not client specific

Tags: windows, mac, keymap, synergy

This question asks about the end key but the answers give no examples: [What key works like End using a Mac with Synergy](https://superuser.com/questions/60052/what-key-works-like-end-using-a-mac-with-synergy)

If they had, I am guessing that they would likely have run into this problem.

Adding lines like the bottom two of this:

```
section: options
    keystroke(End) = keystroke(Control+Right,myMac)
    keystroke(Home) = keystroke(Control+Left,myMac)
```

to my synergy.sgc in MyDocuments on the winXP machine would work but causes the keys to stop functioning on the winXP machine.  Unacceptable.  I next tried a compromise:

```
    keystroke(End) = keystroke(Control+Right,myMac); keystroke(End,myPc)
    keystroke(Home) = keystroke(Control+Left,myMac); keystroke(Home,myPc)
```

Expecting that to broadcast the keystrokes to both machines regardless of which one was the Active Screen.  That and many other variations did not work.

What am I doing wrong?  Has someone actually done this?

EDIT: note that holding shift also prevents synergy from mapping the end key.

EDIT: note that the above assumes that your synergy.sgc also has something like the following:

```
section: screens
    myMac:
        alt = ctrl
        ctrl = alt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should do this directly on the Mac, instead of trying to do it via Synergy? There are a few solutions out there, one I've seen is this one:

- [KeyFixer](http://www.starryhope.com/tech/apple/2006/keyfixer/)

This fixes it most places, but a few apps might not get fixed, so you might need to apply specific settings to them. Googling should find them, for example here are a few:   [Mac Home and End Keys](http://www.popcornfarmer.com/2008/04/mac-home-and-end-keys/)

Comment: Excellent, KeyFixer works for me in mac OS 10.6.2.  It is superior to using DoubleCommand, because DoubleCommand won't remap when used with synergy; for some reason it only affects the dedicated keyboard on the mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "fix" even more annoyances, you could do it manually:

Go to your `~/Library` folder and add a `KeyBindings` folder.
There, create a `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file and copy & paste the following:

```
{  
"\UF729"   = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";                       /* Home         */  
"@\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";                   /* Cmd  + Home  */  
"$\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";     /* Shift + Home */  
"@$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Cmd  + Home */  
"\UF72B"   = "moveToEndOfLine:";                             /* End          */  
"@\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfDocument:";                         /* Cmd  + End   */  
"$\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";           /* Shift + End  */  
"@$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:";       /* Shift + Cmd  + End */  
"\UF72C"   = "pageUp:";                                      /* PageUp       */  
"\UF72D"   = "pageDown:";                                    /* PageDown     */  
"$\UF728"  = "cut:";                                         /* Shift + Del  */  
"$\UF727"  = "paste:";                                       /* Shift + Ins */  
"@\UF727"  = "copy:";                                        /* Cmd  + Ins  */  
"$\UF746"  = "paste:";                                       /* Shift + Help */  
"@\UF746"  = "copy:";                                        /* Cmd  + Help (Ins) */  
"@\UF702"  = "moveWordBackward:";                            /* Cmd  + LeftArrow */  
"@\UF703"  = "moveWordForward:";                             /* Cmd  + RightArrow */  
"@$\UF702" = "moveWordBackwardAndModifySelection:";   /* Shift + Cmd  + Leftarrow */  
"@$\UF703" = "moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:";   /* Shift + Cmd  + Rightarrow */  
}
```

This particular mapping assumes that you have already switched the Control and Command keys.
You might have to restart the app you want this running for and/or log out and log back in.

I'm sorry I can't remember where on the net I found this. But big thumb up for the creator!